# Complexity when loop runs log times

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity

If we're finding the no. of factors of a number, we can use the following efficient loop.
for(i=1;i<=sqrt(n);i++), where n is the 'no' whose factors are to be found. This loop would have a complexity of O(n).

What would be the time complexity of the below code snippet? (Assume that log(x) returns log value in base 2). O(n^2) or O (n logn)? (I assume that log n is the complexity when the loop divides by two. ie. i/=2)

```
void fun()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=log(i);j++)
            printf("hello world");
}
```

Comment: Yes, homework is fun :-)

Comment: In Stack Overflow we expect people to put some effort into their work, before asking for help. And to explain what have they tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual number of "Hello world" prints in your code is:

[image]

You can then use the [Srinivasa Ramanujan approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n) of log(n!):

[image]

To get the actual complexity of the whole code, which is O(n logn)

Comment: I assume that log n is the complexity when the loop divides by two. ie. i/=2

Comment: Yes, a for loop like `for (i=1; i<=n; i*=2)` or `for (i=n; i>=1; i/=2)` runs in O(logn), but there is no such loop in your question. Here the logn term comes from the `j<=log(i)` condition in the second loop.

Comment: but as I wrote in the first three lines that that program's complexity would be O(n) even after the loop runs sqrt(n) times. So how does log n term come after j<=log(i) in place of O(n) as in the previous case?

Comment: Well I'm afraid I don't get what you mean, neither do I get the link between the "find the factors of a number" problem and the code snippet you provided... And if saying that the loop `for(i=1;i<=sqrt(n);i++)` complexity is O(n) is true, it actually runs in O(sqrt(n))

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop calls `printf` approximately `log(i)` times, for `i` in range `[1..n]`. The total number of calls is approximately

```
log(1)+log(2)+log(3)+...log(n) = log(n!)
```

Now, the Stirling asymptotic formula will give you the solution.

---

For the base 2 logarithm, the exact count is given by

```
0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + ... + floor(Lg(n))
```

or

```
1.0 + 2.1 + 4.2 + 8.3 + ... + k.floor(Lg(n))
```

For convenience, assume that `n` is of the form `n=2^m-1`, so that the last run is complete (and `k=2^(m-1)`).

Now take the sum of `x^k` from `0` to `m-1`, which equals `(x^m-1)/(x-1)` and derive on `x` to get the sum of `x^k.k`. Evaluating for `x=2`, you get

```
s = m.2^m-2^m+2 = (n+1).Lg(n+1)-n+1
```

For other `n`, you need to add a correction term for the last partial run. With `m=floor(Lg(n+1))`:

```
t = m.(n+1-2.2^m)
```

Answer (score 0):

An upper bound of O(n*Log(n)) can be proven without any math.

```
void fun()
{
   int i,j;
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       for(j=1;j<=log(n);j++)    // << notice I changed "i" to "n" 
           printf("hello world");
}
```

The above function will run N times the inner loop, and the inner loop will run log(N) times.

Hence, the function will run *exactly* nLog(n) times.

Since this function

```
 (log(n) + log(n) + ... + log(n)) // n times
```

is larger than the OP version

```
(log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n))
```

Then it is an upper bound of the original version.

<= O(n log(n)

#### comment

also

```
(log(n) + log(n) + ... + log(n)) // n times
= log(n^n)
= n*log(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

`j` is dependent on `j`, therefore unroll the dependency, means analyze for `i` only

if `i=1` ----> inner loop executes `log(1)` times

if `i=2` ----> inner loop executes `log(2)` times

if `i=3` ----> inner loop executes `log(3)` times

.

.

if `i=n` ----> inner loop executes `log(n)` times.

combine them ==> `log(1)+log(2)+.....+log(n) = log ( 1.2.3...n ) = log ( n! ) = n log(n)`